# Changing Device type on existing application

Tags: iphone, ipad, flurry

I've made an application on Flurry for iPhone. I wanted to use the same app-id for iPhone and iPad version. The iPad version got published first. But I now need to have a separate app-id and statistics for iPhone version.
Is there a way I can change the device type on application, without changing the app-id, since the app is already published. I want to change the application device from iPhone to iPad. I can create a new one for iPhone.

And is there any difference if the device mentioned in flurry remains as iPhone, but the application runs on iPad??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found out is the device type is just to categories the applications, so that we can have a device-wise stats too. There's no other implications on device type in Flurry, as far as iPhone and iPad is concerned.  I've added another version with some UI changes, and corrected the Device type in that. There's no other option besides that.

Answer (score 1):

how does Flurry detect and store device type? If it does by itself by looking in device specs, it should detect when it runs on ipad. If it takes data from application's settings (plist, whatever), it's a problem, as you specified iphone only. If you can tell Flurry the type, just tell it in

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) 
    //tell Flurry we are running on iphone 
else 
    //...on ipad
```

Comment: I can't change anything in code since the app is published already, and without any major change I can't publish a new version, just for this. I want to know, if there's any setting on flurry site or not?

Comment: Whether you make another upload with the new changes, or read Flurry's docs.